# Powershell regex missing ones with CR etc

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working on a regular expression to extract a map of key and associated string.

For some reason, it's working for lines that don't show a line split, but misses where there are line splits.

This is what I'm using:

```
  $errorMap = [ordered]@{}
  # process the lines one-by-one
  switch -Regex ($fileContent -split ';') {
    'InsertCodeInfo\(([\w]*), "(.*)"' { # key etc., followed by string like "Media size cassette missing"
      $key,$value = ($matches[1,2])|ForEach-Object Trim
      $errorMap[$key] = $value
    }
}
```

This is an example of $fileContent:

```
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlWarnCommunications, 
        "communications error");
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlNormalOnline, 
        "Online");
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlWarnOffline, 
        "offline");
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlNormalAccessing, "Accessing");  #this is first match :(
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlNormalArrive, "Normal arrive");
    InsertCodeInfo(pljNormalProcessing, "Processing");
    InsertCodeInfo(pjlNormalDataInBuffer, "Data in buffer");
```

It's returning the pairs from pjlNormalAccessing down, where it doesn't have a line split.  I thought that using the semicolon to split the regex content would fix it, but it didn't help.  I was formerly splitting regex content with

> '\r?\n'

I thought maybe there was something going on with VSCode so I have exited and re-opened it, and re-running the script had the same result.  Any idea how to get it to match every InsertCodeInfo through the semicolon line with the key-value pair?

This is using VSCode and Powershell 5.1.

Update:

Someone asked how $fileContent is created:

I call my method with the filenamepath ($FileHandler), and from/to strings/methodNames ($matchFound2 becomes $fileContent later as a method parameter):

```
$matchFound2 = Get-MethodContents -codePath $FileHandler -methodNameToReturn "OkStatusHandler::PopulateCodeInfo" -followingMethodName "OkStatusHandler::InsertCodeInfo"

Function Get-MethodContents{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param ( [string]$codePath, [string]$methodNameToReturn, [string]$followingMethodName)
  Process
  {
      $contents = ""
      Write-Host "In GetMethodContents method File:$codePath method:$methodNameToReturn followingMethod:$followingMethodName"  -ForegroundColor Green

      $contents = Get-Content $codePath -Raw #raw gives content as single string instead of a list of strings

      $null = $contents -match  "($methodNameToReturn[\s\S]*)$followingMethodName" #| Out-Null  

      return $Matches.Item(1) 
  }#End of Process
}#End of Function
```

Comment: Does `"([^"]*)"` instead of `"(.*)"` help?

Comment: is `$fileContent` one big multi-line string or an array of strings? How did you produce it in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - see Update in the question for how $fileContent is obtained.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - We can't add ^ to the second match because they aren't at the beginning of the second line.  Some are in mid-line, some are after spaces on the following line.

Comment: `[^"]` has nothing to do with start of a line. It just matches any char except `"` including line break chars. `"([^"]*)"` simply matches from `"` till the next `"` capturing what is in between into a group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I tried your suggestion and the first match is still Accessing...

Comment: @Michele I added the answer with explanation of all parts. Note you do not have to place single shorthand character classes into character classes. See my Youtube video called [Writing cleaner regular expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efsvvVob4Ok) regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
InsertCodeInfo\((\w+),\s*"([^"]*)
```

See the [**online regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zfOPYy/1).

*Details*:

- `InsertCodeInfo\(` - a literal `InsertCodeInfo(` text
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (letters, digits, diacritics or underscores (connector punctuation)
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than a `"` char.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression seems to be catching all lines, including ones with newline in the middle.  Thanks for the suggestion @WiktorStribizew.  I tweaked your suggestion, and it helped.

```
InsertCodeInfo\(([\w]*),[\s]*"([^"]*)
```

It might be the most succinct, but it's catching all lines.  Feel free as always to post alternative suggestions. This is why I didn't accept my own answer.